# ValueError: 'max' is not a supported norm

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bigdata

I am using [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) fine with l1 and l2 norms. I want to try max too, since it mentions:

> norm : ‘l1’, ‘l2’, or ‘max’

So I did:

```
X = tfidf.fit_transform(data['Content']) # the matrix articles x max_features(=words)
normed_X = normalize(X, axis=0, norm='max')
```

and got this runtime error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 427, in normalize
    raise ValueError("'%s' is not a supported norm" % norm)
ValueError: 'max' is not a supported norm
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Probably, old `scikit-learn` package? Could you open the *"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py"* file an post here `if` statement just above `raise` statement? For me it looks like `if norm not in ('l1', 'l2', 'max'):` and accepts `'max'` as well.

Comment: Exactly @soon, sorry for not responding .. soon :) I see `if norm not in ('l1', 'l2'):` and I also checked the comments in `normalize()`. Are you going to post an answer?

Comment: Well, Mike already posted the answer, and I think, that you should accept it - my answer would be effectively the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using documentation that is newer than the library version you are using. The `'max'` option was just added in 0.17.